# Sending email in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

hii 
every one,
I m creating an project
in which Admin is one user
I want code or any idea how can Admin send a quotation of any type of products to his 
customer though email on their email ID

and this quotation has to be a print option button
bec. after clicking on print button quotation  should be print

How can i do it?

Comment: Do you just need code to e-mail something? Or are you trying to print something?

Comment: both ,, I want code for mail file in which it must have a print button for print page/file

Comment: @Hussain did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

try this code surely this will work.

Try this link http://www.dotnetspider.com/projects/577-Send-Mail-with-Attachments-using-Gmail.aspx

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sends an mail message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from">Sender address</param>
    /// <param name="to">Recepient address</param>
    /// <param name="bcc">Bcc recepient</param>
    /// <param name="cc">Cc recepient</param>
    /// <param name="subject">Subject of mail message</param>
    /// <param name="body">Body of mail message</param>
    public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc, string cc, string subject, string body)
    {
        // Instantiate a new instance of MailMessage
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        // Set the sender address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
        // Set the recepient address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

    // Check if the bcc value is null or an empty string


  if ((bcc != null) && (bcc != string.Empty))
    {
        // Set the Bcc address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
    }
    // Check if the cc value is null or an empty value
    if ((cc != null) && (cc != string.Empty))
    {
        // Set the CC address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
    }       // Set the subject of the mail message
    mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
    // Set the body of the mail message
    mMailMessage.Body = body;

    // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
    mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
    mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
    SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    // Send the mail message
    mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gu has an article that will help on [Sending Email With System.Mail](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx)

Comment: What didn't work? Post your exact code and the error you got, and perhaphs we can help.