# Send email of ASP.net Page HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce

let say I have shopping cart I send all detail to one page name as `emailsender.aspx`
this page read all cart information(products,qty,price) from session and show it in datarepeater control then i want this page html so i can email this ....

how can i achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in asp .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456166/sending-email-in-asp-net). You will need to formulate the message mark-up, but that's a different question.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, I don't think he's asking how to email. He wants to get the HTML so he can email it. Question isn't clear though.

Comment: @George: I figured the OP wanted both. Yep, unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the HTML that a control produces, you could use code below, found [here](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/859.aspx).

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```